# OpenGL ES 2.0 : how many Shader Programs can be active at the same time

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

Ok this is probably a very basic question, but I've been digging in the Specs and online forums for more than a day without any luck, I know there is a maximum number of 'bound' textures that I can have , is this also the case for shaders and shader programs? and if so how can I query; lets say how many vertex shaders and how many shader programs are supported by the Graphic card?
lastly is GLES20.glUseProgram() a costly operation? switching the ActiveTexture between bound textures isn't but what about switching between shader programs (that if I can have more than one)
Thanks